# How to create a relationship without NULL tables?

Tags: qgis, relationship-class

I made a relation (1:n) between 2 tables. Not every element from the parent layer has a connection with features from the child layer. The relation is made between 'Tipo de Estrutura' Field and 'Est' Field like shown below.

[image: Creation of the Relationship]

[image: Table of content (1) Fathers Layer (2) Child Layer]

The relation is made correctly. My problem is with the elements that have no relation (Example 'Rocha'). When I open the 'identify feature' of 'Rocha' Element is shown a relationship table with no elements. It is possible to only show relation when exist or hide this connection?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is that I did not make a join but a relationship. Can not filter a relation.